# Modulation of real-valued signal

Tags: frequency, modulation, signal-power

I have one doubt according to modulation of a real signal.

there are so many examples where the real signal was modulated with frequency bigger then 0.

**Why the signal could not be putted in f=0?**

is there connection with a sending power?
( Antenna send bandpass signal $\rightarrow$ signal is matched $\rightarrow$antenna send low P $\rightarrow$power will be reflected, Tx get P again)

Comment: Hi Lena! Modulation with frequency *0* is in fact no modulation... And yes electromagnetic concerns apply for such a case.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the transmission medium (the so-called *communication channel*). Some media do not tolerate components at DC (i.e., zero frequency) or near DC. A typical channel where a carrier frequency greater than zero is required is the radio channel.